# Can no longer upload function code in AWS Lambda. Options greyed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I can no longer upload new code in AWS Lambda as it's greyed out.

I am the account holder so should have all the rights. Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image]

Is it possible that the function which has NodeJS 8.10 is no longer supported and I need to create a new function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html) page you can see that Node.js 8.10 was deprecated March 6, 2020.

Deprecation occurs in two phases. During the first phase, you can no longer create functions that use the deprecated runtime. For at least 30 days, you can continue to update existing functions that use the deprecated runtime. After this period, both function creation and updates are disabled permanently. However, the function continues to be available to process invocation events.

You will however be able to change your runtime to a newer version of node and then you'll be able to update your function with new code.